# Expected value of $(\overline{X} - 5)^2$?

Tags: probability, statistics

$X_1, \ldots, X_9$ are 9 random samples from a N(5, 9). I am looking for the distribution ofExpected value of $(\overline{X} - 5)^2$.

$$E[(\overline{X} - 5)^2] = E[\overline{X}^2 - 10\overline{X}  + 25]$$

$$= E[\overline{X}^2] - 10E[\overline{X}]  + 25$$

1. Now I am not sure what to do as I can't say $E[\overline{X}^2] = E[\overline{X}]E[\overline{X}]$ as we don't have independence.
2. Also does the distribution $(\overline{X} - 5)^2$? have some relation to the $\chi$ squared distribution? (I seem to recall something like this although we hardly touched on $\chi$  squared distributions so I am not sure of the relationship).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\mathbb E \bar X = \mathbb E\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{9} = \frac 1 9\left( (\mathbb E(X_1)+\cdots+\mathbb E(X_9)\right) = \frac 1 9 (5+\cdots+5) = 5.
$$
$$
\operatorname{var}\bar X = \operatorname{var}\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{9} = \frac{1}{81}( \operatorname{var}(X_1)+\cdots+\operatorname{var}(X_9)) = \frac{1}{81}(9 + \cdots+9) = 1.
$$

Therefore $\mathbb E((\bar X-5)^2)=\operatorname{var}(\bar X) = 1$.

All that works even without knowing that the distribution is normal.  With that additional information, we can say $\bar X\sim N(5,1)$, so $\bar X -5 \sim N(0,1)$.  Therefore $(\bar X-5)^2\sim\chi^2_1$.

Comment: Is this line a typo -

Therefore $\mathbb E((\bar X-5)^2)=\operatorname{var}(\bar X) = 1$. I don't see how you arrived at this conclusion.

Comment: @sonicboom : I don't see why it would be suspected of being a typo.  If $Y$ is a random variable with finite variance and $\mu=\mathbb E(Y)$ then $\mathbb E((Y-\mu)^2)=\operatorname{var}(Y)$. ${}\qquad{}$